# How to slow down an animation in its middle while being executed?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, translate-animation, slowdown

As the question is clearly stated, I want to slow down a TranslateAnimation while it is being executed when a user clicks on a certain button.

**This is how I instantiate the TranslateAnim where `-textViewHeight` and `layoutHeight` are just some values I already instantiated in earlier time:**

It goes from up to bottom.

```
TranslateAnim translateAnim = new TranslateAnim(0, 0, -textViewHeight, layoutHeight);
translateAnim.setDuration(20000);
translateAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
textView.startAnimation(translateAnim);
```

**This is the method where I want to slow the TranslateAnim down:**

It didn't work as I expected though.

```
public void slowDown() {
    translateAnim.setStartTime(translateAnim.getStartTime() - 20000);
    translateAnim.setDuration((20000 - translateAnim.getElapsedTime()) * 2);
}
```

I also tried doing that but still no luck:

```
translateAnim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
```

**My custom TranslateAnim class extending TranslateAnimation:**

```
public class TranslateAnim extends TranslateAnimation {

    private long mElapsedAtPause, elapsedTime;
    private boolean mPaused = false;

    public TranslateAnim(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta) {
        super(fromXDelta, toXDelta, fromYDelta, toYDelta);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getTransformation(long currentTime, Transformation outTransformation) {
        if (mPaused && mElapsedAtPause == 0) {
            mElapsedAtPause = currentTime - getStartTime();
        }
        if (mPaused) {
            setStartTime(currentTime - mElapsedAtPause);
        }
        elapsedTime = currentTime - getStartTime();
        return super.getTransformation(currentTime, outTransformation);
    }

    public long getElapsedTime() {
        return elapsedTime;
    }

    public void slowDown() {
        translateAnim.setStartTime(translateAnim.getStartTime() - 20000);
        translateAnim.setDuration((20000 - translateAnim.getElapsedTime()) * 2);
    }

    public void pause() {
        mElapsedAtPause = 0;
        mPaused = true;
    }

    public void resume() {
        mPaused = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        super.cancel();
        elapsedTime = 0;
        mElapsedAtPause = 0;
        mPaused = false;
    }
}
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom Interpolator instead of a linear one.  A linear one causes it to have equal time slices. A custom one can have the time slices in the middle be longer.

For example:

```
public class CustomInterpolator implements Interpolator {

    public boolean slowMode;
    float lastInput;
    float lastInputBeforeSlowed;

    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float input) {
        if (!slowMode) {
            //Should be edited
            lastInput = input;
            return input;
        } else {
            return (input - lastInputBeforeSlowed) * .5f + lastInputBeforeSlowed;
        }
    }

    public void enterSlowMode() {
        slowMode = true;
        lastInputBeforeSlowed = lastInput;
    }

    public void endSlowMode() {
        slowMode = false;
        //Should be edited
    }
}
```

Comment: I already know that, but the purpose of my question was to do that while it was being executed in the middle of the animation. So unfortunately this won't work.

Comment: It still works.  Have a function on the interpolator that tells it to go into slow mode.  Call it when the button is clicked.  You'll have to play with it a bit, but the right answer is the Interpolator.

Comment: Ahh, I understood you know. I will try doing that then I will reply to you.

Comment: Put up an example that should slow it by 50%.  It might have a problem with a jump when it enters slow mode, you'll have to check.

Comment: I tried like what you did, but there is still that jump like you said. It also occurs if I used the other two solutions I posted in my question. That jump glitch is the problem.

Comment: Try what I just edited, I think that will fix the jump.  Basically it smoothes the interpolation so it doesn't move backward but just increases more slowly after that.

Comment: I have tried your updated solution. Everything works perfectly now, no jumping occurs anymore, but there is still one problem left. I want the textView that is being animated to reach the same distance as if it was going through the normal speed. In other words, if I slow the animation down, the textView won't complete the distance it should have gone through since it is slowed down and the animation duration is still the same. So what should be changed is the duration of the animation. Now how shall I do it?

Comment: I tried implementing your solution along with `translateAnim.setDuration((20000 - translateAnim.getElapsedTime()) * 2);`, but still the jumping would occur again. How to fix that?

Comment: `getElapsedTime()` returns the time that the animation has lasted so far.

Comment: Try 40000-getElapsedTime

Comment: Still no luck. The jumping still occurs. :|

Comment: Alright, I have doubled the duration of the whole animation instead of changing it during execution. So everything works perfectly now except that I also want to end that slow mode at certain time, which will be called by the user. So I want to be able to continue the animation in its normal speed anytime I want without that jumping which occurs. I have updated your answer and simplified some stuff. Any fix to this?